# Java JProgressBar does not show up by setVisible(true)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety

I have a method like below.

`ProgressWindow` is a sub class of `JFrame` containing `JProgressBar`.

`addProgress()` increments a value in the `JProgressBar`.

If I call this method from a method in another class, a frame of `ProgressWindow` will show up but not `JProgressBar` and some `JLabels` inside the frame.  They show up after the last line (`System.out.println("finish")`).

If I call this method in a main method in the class containing this method, then every component (Bar, labels...) instantly shows up.

What can I do for showing the window correctly?

```
static void search(){
  ProgressWindow window = new ProgressWindow();
  window.setVisible(true);
  ExecutorService execs = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime
            .getRuntime().availableProcessors());
  Collection<Callable<Void>> processes = new LinkedList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    processes.add(new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            progressWindow.addProgress(); // increment progress value
            return null;
        }
        });
    }
    try {
        execs.invokeAll(processes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        execs.shutdown();
    }
    System.out.println("finish");
```

Comment: JProgressBar.value this how i change value of progressbar.what is your ProgressWindow

Comment: There are a number of potential risks with your code for violation of the single thread rules in Swing.  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: It sounds like you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread in some way.  Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is you seem to be calling `search` from the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

The problem occurs because you are using `execs.invokeAll` which blocks until all the `callables` have finished running.

This means that the EDT is unable to process new events in Event Queue, including repaint events, this is why your UI is coming to a stand still...

There are a number of issues you are now going to face...

1. You should never update/modify a UI component from any thread other than the EDT
2. You should block the EDT for any reason
3. You seem to want to know when the search is complete, so you know need some kind of event notification...

The first thing we need is some way to be notified that the search has completed, this means you can no longer rely on `search` returning when the search is complete...

```
public interface SearchListener {
    public void searchCompleted();
}
```

Next we need an intermeditate `search` method that builds the UI and ensure that the search is launched within it's own `Thread`...

```
static void search(final SearchListener listener) {
  final ProgressWindow window = new ProgressWindow();
  window.setVisible(true);

  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        search(listener, window);
    }
  });
  t.start();
}
```

Then we need to modify the original `search` method to utilise the `SearchListener` interface to provide notification when the search is complete...

```
static void search(final SearchListener listener, final ProgressWindow window){
  ExecutorService execs = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime
            .getRuntime().availableProcessors());
  Collection<Callable<Void>> processes = new LinkedList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    processes.add(new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            // This method needs to ensure that 
            // what ever it does to the UI, it is done from within
            // the context of the EDT!!
            progressWindow.addProgress();
            return null;
        }
        });
    }
    try {
        execs.invokeAll(processes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        execs.shutdown();
    }
    System.out.println("finish");
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listener.searchCompleted();
        }
    });        
}
```

Now, without the source code for `addProgress`, I might be tempted to use

```
processes.add(new Callable<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressWindow.addProgress();
            }            
        });
        return null;
    }
    });
}
```

Instead...

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand what was going on.
But how can I wait the new thread for searching but let EDT go during waiting. Should I change structure of the code maybe?
Anyway I will try them. Thank you again for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you what you're wanting to do is invoke the setVisible on the Swing UI thread, you can do this with [invokeAndWait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

So something like:

```
final ProgressWindow window = new ProgressWindow();
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
        window.setVisible(true);                
    }
});
```

Comment: Or a Swing `Timer` or a `SwingWorker`...but which is right for the context of the OP?